# How to make and use an arraylist of functions

Tags: arraylist, kotlin

How can i make an arraylist of functions, and call each function easily? I have already tried making an `ArrayList<Function<Unit>>`, but when i tried to do this:

```
functionList.forEach { it }
```

and this:

```
for(i in 0 until functionList.size) functionList[i]
```

When i tried doing this: `it()` and this: `functionList[i]()`, but it wouldn't even compile in intellij. How can i do this in kotlin? Also, does the "Unit" in `ArrayList<Function<Unit>>` mean return value or parameters?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I want to return void and i dont want to take any parameters. I accidentaly added the java tag, but i just removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like this:

```
val funs:List<() -> Unit> = listOf({}, { println("fun")})
funs.forEach { it() }
```

The compiler can successfully infer the type of `funs` here which is `List<() -> Unit>`. Note that `() -> Unit` is a function type in Kotlin which represents a function that does not take any argument and returns `Unit`.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two problems with the use of the `Function` interface here.

The first problem is that it doesn't mean what you might think.  As I understand it, it's a very general interface, implemented by *all* functions, however many parameters they take (or none).  So it doesn't have any `invoke()` method.  That's what the compiler is complaining about.

`Function` has several sub-interfaces, one for each 'arity' (i.e. one for each number of parameters): `Function0` for functions that take no parameters, `Function1` for functions taking one parameter, and so on.  *These* have the appropriate `invoke()` methods.  So you could probably fix this by replacing `Function` by `Function0`.

But that leads me on to the second problem, which is that the Function interfaces aren't supposed to be used this way.  I think they're mainly for Java compatibility and/or for internal use by the compiler.

It's usually much better to use the Kotlin syntax for function types: `(P1, P2...) -> R`.  This is much easier to read, and avoids these sorts of problems.

So the real answer is probably to replace `Function<Unit>` by `() -> Unit`.

Also, in case it's not clear, Kotlin doesn't have a `void` type.  Instead, it has a type called `Unit`, which has exactly one value.  This might seem strange, but makes better sense in the type system, as it lets the compiler distinguish functions that return without an explicit value, from those which don't return.  (The latter might always throw an exception or exit the process.  They can be defined to return `Nothing` -- a type with no values at all.)